# Mongo Aggregation query to equivalent Spring Mongo Data

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb

I am currently stuck with converting below query to spring mongo data code.

> db.getCollection('collectionName').aggregate([   { "$match": {
> "_id": { "$in": [11869099,11111] }    }},   { $project: {
> behavior_traces: {$filter: {
> input: '$behavior_traces',
> as: 'behavior_trace',
> cond: {$eq: ['$$behavior_trace.event_type',{event_type:"candidateImage"}]}
> }}
> }},   { $project: {
> behavior_traces:{ $arrayElemAt: [ "$behavior_traces", -1 ] }
> }} ])

I have first MatchOperation and second Projection working as below, but could not add third projection to fetch last element of array of each document:

```
private MatchOperation getMatchOperation(List<Integer> candidateUserIds) {
    Criteria inCriteria = Criteria.where("_id").in(candidateUserIds);
    return match(inCriteria);
}

private ProjectionOperation getFilterProjectOperation() {
    return project().and(filter("behavior_traces")
            .as("behavior_trace")
            .by(valueOf(
                    "behavior_trace.event_type.event_type")
                    .equalToValue(
                            "candidateImage")))
            .as("behavior_traces");
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is your code:

```
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ArrayOperators.ArrayElemAt; 

private ProjectionOperation getArrayProjectOperation() {
            return project("")
                .and(ArrayElemAt.arrayOf("behavior_traces").elementAt(-1).as("behavior_traces"));
        }
```

**OR**

```
private ProjectionOperation getArrayProjectOperation() {
            return project("")
                    .and("behavior_traces").arrayElementAt(-1).as("behavior_traces");
}
```